# What's the difference between [:5] and [5] in this Python code?

Tags: python, linear-regression, train-test-split

What's the difference between `[:5]` and `[5]` in this Python code?

```py
y_test_predicted = model.predict(X_test)

residuals = Y_test   -   y_test_predicted

print(residuals[:5])

print(residuals[5])
```

Comment: You need to take a few steps back and study basic Python syntax and list *slicing*. Please take some time with the excellent [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/).

Comment: `5` is just an index, `:5` is a *slice*, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Comment: Not all use cases require to really learn Python. I wanted to translate python algorithms to Javascript with a package `opencv4nodejs` that execute compiled c++ code. When I see `cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:5]`, I already know intuitively to use `Array.prototype.sort` and `Array.prototype.reverse` if necessary. But `[:5]` is not intuitive to go for `Array.prototype.slice` or `Array.prototype.splice`. If I want to translate more complex codes, I would rather learn Python fully and switch directly to Python instead.

Answer (score 4):

you can find a useful information about slicing in this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-comprehension-and-slicing/).

Refer to below simple example to understand it as a glimpse:

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'i', 'j']
print(list[5]) #it will print: f
print(list[:5]) #it will print:  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], indices form 0 to 4
#List Slicing: list[start:stop:step]
```